# Why cant i see HTML source for big websites like Google and Facebook?

Tags: javascript, web

I have recently taken an interest in software development. I have gotten pretty good by looking at source code, and visiting stack overflow regularly. I have since taken a liking to web applications due to their scalability. Because of this, I wanted to look at the source code of Facebook and Google in a web browser by **clicking "View Source"**.

Funnily enough, **clicking "View Source"** on Google and Facebook does NOT show HTML Markup, but a full page of minified Javascript (at least i think its JS) instead. I have attached a screen shot to show what I mean. How does this work? From what I have learnt along the way, a browser requires HTML to display content. My Assumption is that large companies do this to protect their source. But how does a browser know what to display? And if a browser can display these sites properly, from what source code is it reading from?

I have tried to google this, but search terms such as "cant view Facebook source" or "Cant view Google Source" show me a bunch of un related results.

Is this a framework I have not heard of? Can anyone provide explanation on this. If these large companies are using these new methods, I would like to incorporate them into my own arsenal.

Screenshot of what is visible when you click "View Source" on the Google search results page:

[image]

Comment: there are HTML tags in there, what do you think by 'HTML source'?

Comment: javascript inside <script> tags is valid HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to not understand fundamentals of HTML and JavaScript and how they work together in a browser; consider this example from Wikipedia/JavaScript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="hellobutton">Hello</button>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('hellobutton').onclick = function() {
            alert('Hello world!');                     // Show a dialog
            var myTextNode = document.createTextNode('Some new words.');
            document.body.appendChild(myTextNode);     // Append "Some new words" to the page
        };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is HTML markup with embedded JavaScript (you can embed CSS as well). What some people do, for various reasons, is minify the JavaScript to the point where almost everything that makes it human readable is removed -- of course the Javascript runtime (browser) doesn't care and will just as easily execute it regardless of whether it's minified or not.

HTML it self can be minified, but you can't really minify it anymore than removing line breaks, spaces and making it look like a single line without breaking the HTML's syntax/semantics like you can with JavaScript because HTML doesn't have variables.

Now consider the same example from Wikipedia, but minified (JavaScript and HTML)

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html> <head> <title>Example</title> </head> <body> <button id="hellobutton">Hello</button> <script>document.getElementById("hellobutton").onclick=function(){alert("Hello world!");var e=document.createTextNode("Some new words.");document.body.appendChild(e)};</script> </body></html>
```

Both are equally valid for the browser.

---

Additional Info

All the client side code needed to show you the website will always be visible to you. But recently, web developers have been inclined to use more and more JavaScript to add interactivity to their site or generate the HTML dynamically. The the latter case, you will often find that the 'View Source' page have nothing at all expect a `script` tag. You can use the Developer Tools on your browser to inspect this dynamically generated HTML, as well as inspect the various JavaScript scripts that have been loaded for that site.

Keep in mind, that developers can and will often minify their code making it difficult to view the JavaScript easily regardless of how you choose to inspect it.

Best place to see raw, unminified JavaScript if you're interested in on open source web projects on places like GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

The webpage is html-rendered by using compiled source from javascript (Angular or Reactjs or Vue etc.) Using `View source` does not help in this case. You can right-click and choose `Inspect element` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The mess of JavaScript that you're looking at is known as [**minification**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)). Illegibility is indeed a by-product of minification, though the main purpose is to improve loading speeds. Because Facebook and Google are two of the most high-traffic websites in the world, they have to employ a umber of techniques in order to server up content faster.

Minification is performed using a Task Runner like Grunt or Gulp, and essentially does a few things:

- Changes variables like `useful_name` into equally valid short variables like `e`.
- Eliminates all whitespace.
- Rewrites many functions into equal shorter functions.

For example:

```
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  array[i] = i;
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
for(var a=[i=0];++i<20;a[i]=i);
```

Which obviously takes up much fewer bytes.

While the minification helps '**obfuscate**' code, it does not improve security in the slightest, as the obfuscation can be completely decoded.

In addition to minification, it's also common practice to combine multiple different JavaScript or CSS files into one, using bundlers like Browserify, Brunch or webpack. Because of this, it can be quite difficult to work out what the code is really doing, though this can be aided by **[Prettyprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prettyprint)** the files by clicking on the `{}` icons in the bottom left of the relevant source.

Other common load-speed approaches include using **[Content Delivery Networks (CDNs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)**, cutting down on HTTP requests, and using **[sprite mapping](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)** - all of which both of the above do in addition to their minification.

Answer (score 1):

> From what I have learnt along the way, a browser requires HTML to display content.

Check out [this post](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/what-exactly-is-client-side-rendering-and-hows-it-different-from-server-side-rendering-bd5c786b340d) about client side and server side rendering.

Google's front page actually is fully server-side rendered (all the HTML is present on "view source"), it just there's a lot of inlined Javascript before the page body and all of it is also minifed.

Facebook uses JavaScript much more heavily, most parts are written in React (their frontend framework), which is why you will barely see any plain HTML when inspecing Facebook's source. As Jun said, you are however able to inspect it with your browser's inspector after Javascript has rendered all of it.

> My Assumption is that large companies do this to protect their source.

Not really, there's no "protecting" frontend code, it's just that client-side rendering has become much more popular and everybody minifies their source codes for bandwidth savings. On such a large scale (Facebook and Google), every saved byte counts. It might be harder to read, but nothing can actually be hidden or protected as, like you said, browsers need to render and execute the code client-side.